# Compare the values of textbox and pre defined list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am new to coding.
I have pre- defined a string with username and password. I want to write logic to first find Username and then compare Password from respective textbox. 
If username and password match I want to render another file with further code. Thank you. I have edited the code based on comments but still no luck. It directs to else statement when user and password are correct.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace GridView
{
public partial class practise : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    public static List<User> listuser = new List<User>()
   {
            new User() {ID = 1, UserName = "Dhruv", Password = "hello"},
            new User() {ID = 2, UserName = "Gaurav", Password = "12345"},
            new User() {ID = 3, UserName = "Rahul", Password = "asdfg"},
            new User() {ID = 4, UserName = "Guru", Password = "qwerty"}
   };

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            listuser = new List<User>();
            GRIDDATA.DataSource = listuser;
            GRIDDATA.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        User data = new User();
        data.UserName = TextBox1.Text;
        data.Password = TextBox2.Text;

        bool UserExists(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            return listuser.Any(a => a.UserName.Equals(UserName) && a.Password.Equals(Password));
        }

        if(UserExists(data.UserName, data.Password))
        {

            Response.Redirect("https://www.google.com");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("https://www.wwe.com");
        }





    }
}


public class User
{   
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }   
}
}
```

Comment: It would make much more sense to populate `listuser` when you instanciate it instead of on `Page_Load`.

Comment: what is this `foreach(string )` supposed to be?

Comment: The logic I want to write. Foreach (string x in listuser) and then check every username with corressponding username textbox1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring some of the (ahem) more interesting areas of your code and reading your question on face value you want something like:

```
 public static List<User> listuser = new List<User>(){
        new User() {ID = 1, UserName = "Dhruv", Password = "hello"},
        new User() {ID = 2, UserName = "Gaurav", Password = "12345"},
        new User() {ID = 3, UserName = "Rahul", Password = "asdfg"},
        new User() {ID = 4, UserName = "Guru", Password = "qwerty"}
    };

protected bool UserExists(string userName, string password)
{
   return listuser.Any(a => 
              a.UserName.Equals(userName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
              && 
              a.Password.Equals(password));
}
```

I'm using `.Equals(userName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` to make the username comparision case insensitive.

If your adding to `listuser` (`listuser.Add(data);`) you really need to understand you code currently isn't [thread safe and will crash...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941181/are-static-variables-thread-safe-c-sharp)

Comment: how to use UserExists now ? . if (UserExists = true) is not working.

Comment: `==` is the equality comparison not `=`. You also don't need to check for `true` `if(UserExists(username, password))` will do

Comment: bascially this `if (UserExists = true)` isn't valid c#. Read how to invoke a function and how to use equality comparisions

Answer (score 0):

Let me introduce you to `System.Linq;`

It makes searching in generic collections easy.

What you can do instead of your foreach(string) spot is something in the lines of.

```
var loggedInUser = listuser.FirstOrDefault(
    u => u.UserName.Equals(data.UserName) && 
    u.Password.Equals(data.Password)
);
```

Of course for this to work, you have to add `using System.Linq`; at the top of your document.

Then if `loggedInUser` is not `null`, you have a match!

Comment: why create an object just to see if it exists when `Any` will just return a bool?

Comment: Cause I don't know what he wants to do with the user :P if he just wants to know if it exists, then yes, any is sufficient. I just wanted to give him a tool to go and search his own answer instead of telling him how it's done. Since he clearly is still in the learning process.